# Linksys AP losing connection to Linksys main router

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, wireless-router, wireless-access-point

I have a WRT1900 in my basement as a main router, and I have a WRT1200 on the next floor as an AP. They are connected by Ethernet cable. My problem is when I am connected to WRT1200 AP seems like this AP would lose its connection to the main router. I test by letting my laptop ping hundreds of times randomly throughout the day and every so often it would drop connection for 30-60 seconds before fixing itself. The problem doesn't always fix itself though, sometimes I have to reset the routers for the connection to be normal again... until it breaks again. What else could I check for errors between these two units, short of replacing a whole new cable? 
EDIT: Ping results below. Ping ran fine for 667 times, then it dropped packets 27 times, then it was fine again.

```
64 bytes from 192.168.1.1: icmp_seq=664 ttl=63 time=4.075 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.1.1: icmp_seq=665 ttl=63 time=4.724 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.1.1: icmp_seq=666 ttl=63 time=5.353 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.1.1: icmp_seq=667 ttl=63 time=4.035 ms
Request timeout for icmp_seq 668
92 bytes from testwifi.here (192.168.86.1): Destination Net Unreachable
Vr HL TOS  Len   ID Flg  off TTL Pro  cks      Src      Dst
 4  5  00 5400 2888   0 0000  40  01 79a6 192.168.86.41  192.168.1.1 

Request timeout for icmp_seq 669
Request timeout for icmp_seq 670
Request timeout for icmp_seq 671
Request timeout for icmp_seq 672
Request timeout for icmp_seq 673
Request timeout for icmp_seq 674
Request timeout for icmp_seq 675
Request timeout for icmp_seq 676
Request timeout for icmp_seq 677
Request timeout for icmp_seq 678
Request timeout for icmp_seq 679
Request timeout for icmp_seq 680
Request timeout for icmp_seq 681
Request timeout for icmp_seq 682
Request timeout for icmp_seq 683
Request timeout for icmp_seq 684
Request timeout for icmp_seq 685
Request timeout for icmp_seq 686
Request timeout for icmp_seq 687
Request timeout for icmp_seq 688
Request timeout for icmp_seq 689
Request timeout for icmp_seq 690
Request timeout for icmp_seq 691
Request timeout for icmp_seq 692
Request timeout for icmp_seq 693
Request timeout for icmp_seq 694
64 bytes from 192.168.1.1: icmp_seq=695 ttl=63 time=4.230 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.1.1: icmp_seq=696 ttl=63 time=6.853 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.1.1: icmp_seq=697 ttl=63 time=4.068 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.1.1: icmp_seq=698 ttl=63 time=2.843 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.1.1: icmp_seq=699 ttl=63 time=3.746 ms
```

Ping ran fine again from 695 to 1118, then it dropped one packet, and went back up again.

```
64 bytes from 192.168.1.1: icmp_seq=1117 ttl=63 time=4.442 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.1.1: icmp_seq=1118 ttl=63 time=4.044 ms
Request timeout for icmp_seq 1119
64 bytes from 192.168.1.1: icmp_seq=1120 ttl=63 time=10.043 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.1.1: icmp_seq=1121 ttl=63 time=3.660 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.1.1: icmp_seq=1122 ttl=63 time=4.898 ms
```

Thank you

UPDATE: I tested the cables using a Goldtool LAN Tester TCT-2690 and all the cables passed the test, so that’s good I guess. At least the cables are physically fine. I’m back to square one though.

Comment: I have this kind of setup with different make of routers and the connections are stable for years.  Temporarily move the Access point to the main router and connect with a different cable to see if that is the issue. Update the firmware on both routers and restart them.

Comment: Thank you. Someone on this forum once told me I should use the same brand for all my equipment. I thought that was rather strange. How would I do that test efficiently? Because the network could be up and running for many hours, and just suddenly drop packets for 30 seconds, and MAYBE come back again. It is difficult to reproduce manually. Thank you.

Comment: Did you try updating firmware?

Comment: @John yes the main router WRT1900 is using the latest firmware and on auto update.

Comment: Could there be any apps or software on laptops, mobile phones, tablets running within the network that interferes with the network?

Comment: I have 3 computers and 2 phones on my network. Nothing is interfering  with the basic router networking. The phones did try to grab the computer IP addresses (that is not a router problem) and I gave the phones their own IP addresses to prevent this.

Comment: Did you update also the WRT1200?

Comment: @harrymc I did update the stock firmware of the WRT1200, with no change. Now it is running DD-WRT, and it's still happening. I have not yet installed DD-WRT on the WRT1900, would like to see if that helps. What do you think? thank you.

Comment: I don't truly know, but the problem is weird enough. I would also try with a new well-shielded cable.

Comment: @harrymc thank you for your reply. I'm avoiding changing cables if possible, because the cables are in the walls and that's gonna be a super pain in the ass. Are you saying something is interfering with the cables?

Comment: This is one possibility.

Comment: @harrymc what could interfere with cable signals inside the walls?

Comment: Bad shielding or exposed contacts? (I'm not saying this is what happens. Just ideas.)

Comment: Several tests may help to check if it is faulty hardware.
1) Bring both devices next to each other and connect them with another cable. Test again.
2) Can you connect them via WiFi? Do so and test again.
Besides, did this happen from day 0 you have the current configuration? If not, how long ago did it start? Did you do anything close to that time?

Answer (score 1):

You are seeing a lot of packet loss, so it is most likely to be a cabling issue. A poorly installed cable can pass a test from a simple test tool, and still be faulty. You can show ethernet errors with `ip -s link show dev eth0`

Ensure that you are adhering to the correct standard for pair pinouts on your cable - ie both ends should have the same T568A or T568B pinout. This will ensure that any outside interference will correctly be handled by each twisted pair. Replacing the connectors on each end is very cheap and easy if you already own an RJ45 crimp tool.

The other obvious cable issue is physical damage to the cable. Check that it doesn't have any sharp kinks/bends, heat damage, or any other obvious issues. Some issues aren't as obvious, such as moisture or stretching, or a loose/corroded RJ45 connector pin.

Failing that, open each of the routers and see if there is any swelling of any of the capacitors - do an image search for "swollen capacitors" to see that the difference between good and bad capacitors can be subtle, if noticeable at all. There was a time when Linksys was installing cheap capacitors on some of it's product lines which meant they didn't last very long.

To test that it's not the cable, plug a linux PC in one end an run `cat /dev/zero | nc -l 8` on one end, and on the other end, run `nc <otherIPAddress> 8 > /dev/null`. If you open a CLI tool like `iptraf-ng` you should see speeds of at least 70Mb/s for a 100Base-TX connection, and at least 500Mb/s for a 1000Base-T. Another good test for packet loss is `ping -f <ipaddress>` - if your terminal starts to fill up with dots... that's bad.

Of course, it's possible there's an issue with the devices themselves, but again, this can be tested by plugging them into each other with a completely different cable.